# How to split an interleaved text file using bash commands

Tags: bash, text, split

I want to split a text file into multiple single files. Since the command will be executed on a remote cluster, I'm looking at simple bash commands for the job.

The file structure is made of a header followed by the interlaced data.
The header is a line with the number of probes (N) where data is measured and N lines with the probe's position (coordinates).

Then, on each call, N lines are appended with the measured data (time, velocities (x,y,z), pressure, temperature).

The overall structure:

```
N
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
x3 y3 z3
...
xN yN zN
time1 vx1 vy1 vz1 pr1 tmp1
time1 vx2 vy2 vz2 pr2 tmp2
time1 vx3 vy3 vz3 pr3 tmp3
...
time1 vxN vyN vzN prN tmpN
time2 vx1 vy1 vz1 pr1 tmp1
time2 vx2 vy2 vz2 pr2 tmp2
time2 vx3 vy3 vz3 pr3 tmp3
...
time2 vxN vyN vzN prN tmpN
time3 vx1 vy1 vz1 pr1 tmp1
time3 vx2 vy2 vz2 pr2 tmp2
....
```

and it continues until the end of the runtime.

I want to split this file into N individual text files, one for each probe, like this:

```
time1 vx1 vy1 vz1 pr1 tmp1
time2 vx1 vy1 vz1 pr1 tmp1
time3 vx1 vy1 vz1 pr1 tmp1
time4 vx1 vy1 vz1 pr1 tmp1
....
```

First lines of an output with 3 probes:

```
   3
0.0250 0.5000 0.1250
0.0500 0.5000 0.1250
0.1250 0.5000 0.1250
  0.0000000E+00 -1.1340826E-03  6.9640250E-02  1.6186548E-05 -4.0954774E-02 -1.5523269E-02
  0.0000000E+00 -1.5596009E-03 -3.4286277E-02  9.0128932E-05 -4.0959023E-02  6.9194414E-03
  0.0000000E+00 -3.9384158E-05 -2.2799330E-05  1.1221853E-05 -4.0955983E-02 -1.2640788E-06
  4.0196506E-02 -1.6982891E-03  6.9905423E-02  2.3351709E-05 -3.9776587E-02 -1.6820817E-02
  4.0196506E-02 -1.0372577E-03 -3.4509494E-02  6.3698954E-05 -3.9868597E-02  7.5963487E-03
  4.0196506E-02 -6.5377012E-05  3.3921110E-05  3.1376311E-05 -4.0054469E-02  1.0799556E-05
  8.0393012E-02 -1.6714063E-03  7.0387993E-02  1.5038874E-05 -4.0916789E-02 -1.8516903E-02
  8.0393012E-02 -1.1169951E-03 -3.4756862E-02  4.9885574E-05 -4.0875671E-02  8.4853258E-03
  8.0393012E-02 -9.1204643E-05  2.6588890E-05  2.1999171E-05 -4.0515620E-02  1.9732526E-05
  1.2058952E-01 -1.6174557E-03  7.0969499E-02  1.3969087E-05 -3.9974914E-02 -2.0067937E-02
  1.2058952E-01 -1.1945215E-03 -3.4945342E-02  4.9125530E-05 -3.9976085E-02  9.3101819E-03
  1.2058952E-01 -8.3691302E-05  1.0623141E-05  6.2817857E-06 -3.9872920E-02  3.0225340E-05
  1.6078602E-01 -1.5857685E-03  7.1464134E-02  1.4791469E-05 -4.0061323E-02 -2.1601683E-02
  1.6078602E-01 -1.2624167E-03 -3.5139814E-02  5.0977166E-05 -4.0052185E-02  1.0136956E-02
  1.6078602E-01 -6.9232853E-05 -1.8374514E-06 -8.4810929E-06 -3.9979475E-02  4.0127930E-05
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you find?

Comment: Is that the real indentation? Or should there be no whitespace at the beginning of the lines in your example?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I was writting a Fortran script (since it's the language that I've been using the most) but had issues with the amount of opened units (prints started going into open units (depending of the value of N) instead of stdout and I was starting to use more and more system calls, so decided to go with bash. After some researching I found most of the commands (split, csplit) worked in a more serialised fashion.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Is real indentation. The output is generated by a Fortran code with a format with 15 total characters (1p20E15.7). The 14th character is a whitespace or a minus sign and the 15th a white space that separates the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```sh
read n < infile
for ((i = 0; i < n; ++i)); do
    sed -n "$((n+2+i))~${n}p" infile > "outfile$i.txt"
done
```

This reads the first line of your input file into `n`, trimming whitespace, so for the example it'll contain `3`.

Then it loops over `0`, `1`, ..., `n-1`, so for the example: `0`, `1`, `2`, setting `i` to that value. The sed command expands to this:

```sh
sed -n '5~3p' infile > outfile0.txt
sed -n '6~3p' infile > outfile1.txt
sed -n '7~3p' infile > outfile2.txt
```

where the first line address is the result of `n+2+i`, and `3` is the value of `$n`. Output for lines other than those matched is suppressed with `-n`. The output files are numbered using the value of `i`.

Notice that this sed construct for addresses, `n~m` (start at line `n`, then hit every `m`th line) requires GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
awk 'NR==1 {n=$1} NR<=(n+1) {next} {print > sprintf("probe%d",NR%n+1)}' infile
```

this reads `infile` and generated `probeN` files with the corresponding lines.
It's only 1 process, if you have big files it would make a difference.